# Rcedit doesn't works after selecting embed pck file in godot

Tags: export, embed, godot

I installed Rcedit for changing my file icon after exporting my game with Godot 3.2.2 stable.

But it only works when I uncheck embed pck. Else, it says that it can't find pck.

I want to embed the pck file with exe.

I also to change the file icon from default.

What can I do?

Edit: I also noticed now that, Rcedit is not working. It shows the custom icon when I check it in the folder. But when I bring it to desktop, it shows the default icon and it doesn't depends on presence recedit!

I am confused. Can someone solve it.

Comment: "It shows the custom icon when I check it in the folder. But when I bring it to desktop, it shows the default icon and it doesn't depends on presence recedit" That could be Windows icon cache. Search [How to reset the icon cache](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=How%20to%20reset%20the%20icon%20cache).

Comment: I tried to do but, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is now a document known issue: [Export with embedded pck is broken when changing PE metadata with rcedit](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/33466). It has not been solved at the moment of writing. However, it should be solved for the next release (if there is another tool, similar to rcedit, which actually works in this scenario, that would be the solution. For you, and for Godot. I'm unaware of any).

> Godot is not coming today, but will come tomorrow

-- [Waiting For Godot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiting_for_Godot).

Meanwhile, you will have to build your own export templates for Windows. To do that, begin with downloading Godot source.

Go to the [Godot repository](https://github.com/godotengine/godot), select the branch you want (e.g 3.2) or the tag you want (e.g. 3.2.3-stable), and download to zip.

You will need Python. You will need pip, make sure it is up to date (`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`) and install Scons using pip (`python -m pip install scons`). You will also need the C++ build tools. I recommend using the Visual Studio Community installer and select "Desktop development with C++" (you don't really need Visual Studio, however in my experience using the Visual Studio installer to get them is more reliable than the standalone installer). Finally you can run `scons platform=windows` from the Godot source folder to build Godot.

The build system and the build process is explained in more detail in [Introduction to the buildsystem](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/introduction_to_the_buildsystem.html). And, of course, [Compiling for Windows](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_windows.html#doc-compiling-for-windows).

Yet, the goal is not to build Godot. The goal is to build the Windows export templates. For that you are going to run these:

```
C:\godot> scons platform=windows tools=no target=release_debug bits=32
C:\godot> scons platform=windows tools=no target=release bits=32
C:\godot> scons platform=windows tools=no target=release_debug bits=64
C:\godot> scons platform=windows tools=no target=release bits=64
```

Oh, but, wait, before you do that… You need to find `platform/windows/godot.ico` in the source and replace it with the icon you want. Then build the Windows export templates.

Once you have your custom built export templates, you need to put them in `%APPDATA%\Godot\templates\<version>\`, where version matches what about says in Godot, (e.g "3.2.3.stable.mono"). And then you can build your game.

As you know, your game will appear with the default icon. What I describe here changes the default icon.